# What does the "operator <" syntax mean?

Tags: c++11, syntax, stl

I am trying to learn C++ STL..I came across this syntax,not able to figure out what the whole line means!

```
  struct student{ 
   int id,pts;

bool operator < (student x) const{
    return pts>x.pts;
}
}a[150000];
```

Comment: It's an overload for the `<` operator on the `student` type.  The function name is `operator<` but it can be called like: `if (some_student < other_student)`.  The `bool` is just the return type of the function. Note that it looks like there's a bug: the return expression should probably be `pts < x.pts`.

Comment: [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/3309790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator <` is a name to be defined, just like `foo` or `bar`. It behaves just like an identifier.

`bool operator < (student x) const` declares a function as `bool foo (student x) const` would.

The effect is to define usage of the `<` operator between `student` objects. The connection to the STL is that templates related to ordering of objects use expressions like `a < b` to perform the ordering. This comes up in algorithms like `std::sort` and containers like `std::map`.

That particular definition sorts students by points, which isn't a very good system for sorting students. Facilities like `sort` and `map` always provide an alternative to `operator <`, where you can pass a more specific function, say one called `less_points`. Also, since that definition of `operator <` uses the `>` operator internally (without reversing the left- and right-hand sides), it will sort in descending order whereas the usual convention is to use ascending order.

Note, it's common to define `operator <` or `operator ==` without defining `>`, `!=`, or the other relational operators. The standard library only ever cares about `<` and `==`, and boilerplate to get the rest is usually wasted. Likewise it's a good convention to avoid using relations besides `<` and `==` on objects that might not be numbers.

Comment: +1 for bringing out the STL relation, what if I want a custom operator > (descending order)? without a custom operator >,  !(myStudent < yourStudent) is not the same as (myStudent > yourStudent)?

Comment: @Arun The standard library never looks at `operator >`, so defining it gets you no closer to a descending ordering. It's better to define a specific function like `more_points`. You can also define `operator >` and specify `std::greater`, or specify `std::rel_ops::operator > <student>` as the custom function, which is defined in terms of `operator <`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @Potatoswatter for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

it is defining a "less than" operator for the struct `student`, so that people can write:

```
 student one, two;
 bool b = one < two;
```

Answer (score 1):

operator< allows comparing two students, and in this example, it compares only by pts.

```
struct student{ 
   int id,pts;

   bool operator < (student x) const{
    return pts>x.pts; // must be pts<x.pts
  }
}a[150000];
```

lest should it work the other way (operator >), the implementation must use operator '<'

As a good practice, please consider adding custom definition for operator > and operator=, because the comparison is based only on pts (by the definition of operator <)

For the sake of minimal completeness and logical correctness when using comparison operators, please consider adding custom definition for operators > and ==

```
struct student{ 
   int id,pts;

   bool operator < (student x) const{
      return pts<x.pts; 
   }   
   bool operator > (student x) const{
      return pts>x.pts; 
   }
   bool operator == (student x) const{
      return pts == x.pts; 
   }
```

}a[150000];